AES-RSA public/private encryption using C#
I have a project in which I need to send an encrypted payload to FastSpring. There process is as follows:
Create a 2048 RSA public/private certificate pair and upload the
public cert to FastSpring
I am using openssl to generate the keypair.
openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 2048

openssl req -new -key privatekey.pem -x509 -days 3650 -out publiccert.pem

Randomly generated 16-byte AES key
Encrypt the payload using the AES key
Encrypt the AES key using your private cert
Send the encrypted payload and AES key to FastSpring
FastSpring receives the payload and AES key.
Since the AES key was encrypted using my private certificate file, FastSpring will decrypt it using my public certificate file that was uploaded.
FastSpring can now decrypt the encrypted payload using the AES key
https://developer.fastspring.com/reference/pass-a-secure-request
I am using the following code to encrypt the AES key:
string privateKeyText = File.ReadAllText(PathToPrivateKey);    
using RSA privateRsa = RSA.Create();    
privateRsa.ImportFromPem(privateKeyText.ToCharArray());
 
byte[] bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textToEncrypt); //AES Key
byte[] encryptedAesKey = rsa.Encrypt(bytesToEncrypt, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);

However, when they receive the encrypted key, they are unable to decrypt it. I have tested the process on my end and confirmed that an error is thrown when trying to decrypt the message with the public certificate. Here is the decryption code I used to test the process:
using var publicX509 = new X509Certificate2(PathToCertificate); 
RSA publicRsa = publicX509.GetRSAPublicKey();
byte[] decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedAesKey, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256); 
string decryptedAesKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);

When I run the above code I get the following error:
WindowsCryptographicException: Key does not exist. 
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng.EncryptOrDecrypt(SafeNCryptKeyHandle key, ReadOnlySpan`1 input, AsymmetricPaddingMode paddingMode, Void* paddingInfo, Boolean encrypt)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng.EncryptOrDecrypt(Byte[] data, RSAEncryptionPadding padding, Boolean encrypt)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng.Decrypt(Byte[] data, RSAEncryptionPadding padding)
   at UserQuery.DecryptData(Byte[] dataToDecrypt, RSA rsa), line 37
   at UserQuery.Main(), line 20
 
I know that in general, most of the time the way asymmetric RSA encryption is done, encrypting the original message using the public key and then decrypted using the provide key. However, given FastSprings process and other documentation, encryption with the private key, followed by decryption using the public certificate is completely valid. Is this true and if so, what could be causing this error?

Update:
Working with FastSpring support, they sent the following code that correctly/incorrectly implements private/public encryption:

        public static string CreateSecureLoad(string clearText, ref byte[] generatedAesKey)
        {
            RijndaelManaged cryptoAlgo = new RijndaelManaged
            {
                Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
                Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
                KeySize = 128,
                BlockSize = 128
            };

            generatedAesKey = cryptoAlgo.Key;
            var clearTextArrary = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearText);
            var encryptor = cryptoAlgo.CreateEncryptor();

            using (MemoryStream msEncryprt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncryprt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    csEncrypt.Write(clearTextArrary);
                    csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                    var cipher = msEncryprt.ToArray();
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(cipher);
                }
            }

            return "";
        }

        public static string CreateSecureKey(byte[] aesKey, string privateKeyPEM)
        {

            var encryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

            using (var textReader = new StreamReader(privateKeyPEM))
            {
                var pemReader = new PemReader(textReader);
                var keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pemReader.ReadObject();
                encryptEngine.Init(true, keyPair.Private);
            }

            var encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptEngine.ProcessBlock(aesKey, 0, aesKey.Length));

            return encrypted;
        }

        public static string CreateSecureKeyFromPEM(byte[] aesKey, string privateKeyPEM)
        {

            var encryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

            using (TextReader textReader = new StringReader(privateKeyPEM))
            {
                var pemReader = new PemReader(textReader);
                var keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pemReader.ReadObject();
                encryptEngine.Init(true, keyPair.Private);
            }

            var encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptEngine.ProcessBlock(aesKey, 0, aesKey.Length));

            return encrypted;
        }


You have probably misunderstood something. The AES key is encrypted with the public key of the other party. Only this way can the other party perform decryption with their private key.

If the encryption were really carried out with the private key, there would be no confidentiality, because then the decryption would have to be carried out with the public key, which practically everyone can have (hence the term public).

Quite apart from the fact that .NET does not support encryption with the private key: in this case, .NET derives the public key from the private key under the hood and encrypts with the public key. And if an attempt is made to decrypt with the public key, it does not work because the private key is required for decryption. This is the reason for the Key does not exist Exception.

@Topaco - I think you are missing something. If you look at the link, the instructions include "Create a Private/Public certificate pair.
Private: Create a 2048-bit RSA private key. You will use the private key PEM file privatekey.pem to create your secureKey.
Public: Create a 2048-bit RSA public key. Only share this key with FastSpring. FastSpring will use your public key PEM file publiccert.pem to decrypt your payload."
They then say "Use your privateKey PEM string to encrypt ... your secureKey string." and "FastSpring uses ... publiccert.pem to decrypt your securePayload string."

@IAmTimCorey - ...I think you are missing something... Yes, namely the note that the linked documentation uses RSA incorrectly, which is why the AES key is not securely encrypted. I've already pointed out the related security risk and that the native .NET methods do not support such misuse. If the OP still wants to pursue this approach, they need a third-party library that supports this.

@Topaco, I am generating the public/private key pair as follows: //generate the private key
openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 2048
//generate the public key from the private key
openssl req -new -key privatekey.pem -x509 -days 3650 -out publiccert.pem

The problem has nothing to do with key generation. To encrypt with the private key, you need a C# library that supports low level signing (as the Java code in the linked documentation does). As part of this process, the private key is used for encryption (but with the padding of signing and not encryption, which is why it is actually signing and not encryption). A C# library that supports this is C#/BouncyCastle, here you can find a sample code (first code snippet, the one that uses the NoneWithRSA algorithm).

@IAmTimCorey To reinforce what's already been said - that link is just plain wrong.  Signing is done with the private key, encrypting is done with the public key.  Signing provides zero confidentiality - it only provides proof that you hold the private key.
